# How can I subtract columns in Pandas.jl DataFrames?

Tags: pandas, julia

It's the first time I raise a question in this platform, so I hope my format is appropriate.
I have a certain experience with Python Pandas, so you are very welcome to provide answers with Python reference.
I have a Pandas.DataFrame which is returned by read_csv, that consists of dates as strings. Index column is also a date axis. I parse the dates with the following code:

```
function parse_date(date::String)
    format = Dates.DateFormat("d.mm.yyyy")
    return Date(date, format)
end
```

After I apply the date parsing to each and every column of my DataFrame, like:

```
for key in columns(df)
    df[key] = map(parse_date, df[key])
end
```

as `map(parse_date, df)` does not work properly.

Now I need to subtract the dates on the date axis from each and every column of the DataFrame. That is, I would like to replace every column with their difference from the leftmost date axis (preferably in Float64, instead of timedelta). 
Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: As I understood your question, to convert string as date column use df['a']=pd.to_datetime(df['a']),
for convert timedelta to float use df['diff']=df['diff']/datetime.timedelta(days=1).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, yet parse_date awkwardly works faster. I think it is because of Python calls for each column.

Comment: Provide format and try. I'm sure that pandas to_datetime is faster

Comment: Can't you just automatically parse the dates when reading in the csv, with 
    df = pd.read_csv(filename,parse_dates=['columns','to','parse'])

Comment: @n3utrino the option beautifully works, but only when you provide the column names. I would like to apply it to all columns at once, and function cannot infer that my columns are dates when I pass parse_dates = true. Any suggestions on this?